# Separate backend API for frontend and other services

Tags: api, symfony, single-page-application

I have SPA app with backend REST API (Symfony) with JWT authentication and necessary methods to communicate with my frontend app (Angular). And now i want to add another service ( Magento ) to comunicate with my backend.

Should Magento use same methods including authentication or its better to create separate module in my Symfony app with it's own methods?

Answer (score 0):

You should reuse what is possible and makes sense, and only create separate API resources for new functionality. There is no point to create duplicate logic, unless there are differences between the use of the two consumers.